# msbuild compiles 32bit on one machine and 64bit on another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm currently having a strange problem. I have a build server compiling solutions for releases, one specific solution is compiled as 32bit, which it shouldn't, on the build server while all other are build as Any Cpu (running as 64bit).
When using msbuild from the VS command prompt the build is still 32bit on the build server, but on my machine it's 64 bit. This is examined by using corflags (The 64bit compiled version):

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

Where the 32bit has the 32BIT flag set on the buildserver ?

I'm using the same msbuild command: `msbuild /p:Congiruation="Release|Mixed Platforms"` on both machines.

Buildserver is running Windows 2008 R2 standard 64 bit
My machine is Windows 7 64 bit

I have tried to look through the build log, but haven't got a clue what to look for ?

The solution file says the following for the given project:

```
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Comment: I presume you are building a solution with all these projects? Have you checked the build platform in the configuration manager properties of the solution?

Comment: Which version of MSBuild (32 or 64 bit) to used is set in the MSBuild Platform property of your Build Definition

Comment: Yes, it's a solution that is build... I will have a look on the property

Comment: Where to find the  MSBuild Platform property of the Build Definition ?

Comment: Note that the platform target can be set per Build Configuration. Often one forgets to change all configurations...

Comment: @dennis_ler If you go to the Process tab in your build definition and expand "Advanced" you will see the property "MSBuild Platform".

Comment: @HamidShahid, I'm totally lost now ? As far as I can see the build definition is related to Team solutions, right ? Just for clarification, this is a "normal" VS2010 solution build server is Teamcity... Otherwise I need a little more help to find the build definition ?

Comment: @0xA3 This is a simple solution three projects, one is a WIX project, one is unit test and the other one is the one that I'm trying to get to compile so it runs as a 64bit on a 64bit OS. The two non WIX projects are ANY CPU.

Comment: This is a VS2010 disaster.  You fix it by taking a sledge hammer to the Build + Configuration Manager dialog and deleting all these meaningless platform names.  Only AnyCPU makes sense for managed projects.  And you now have a shot at correctly changing the setting that *really* matters: Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target.  Set it to AnyCPU for both for the Debug and the Release configuration.  Updating your VS version is also highly recommended, this stupid VS2010 mistake was fixed.

Comment: @dennis_ler Sorry, I misunderstood your questions. I thought you wanted to know why one version of MSBuild was being used rather than other. I see Hans has suggested the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, after ensuring that the project file was correctly Any CPU for all platforms

```
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{2BA1CBC7-6468-4F66-9EF6-F7EE71EC6091}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

I started getting an outputpath was not set problem on the WIX project. Examining the build exe file on the Teamcity server with corflags now showed that it was correctly compiled. So the problem now was the WIX project. So a little bonus information, to solve the problem in the wix project, I edited the proj file for the exe, adding a Release x86 propertygroup but with a PlatformTarget set to AnyCPU.
This means that the requested outputhpath from WIX exist (Release|x86) but is being compiled as an AnyCPU.